# MYSQL Sum of Multiple Tables Using Primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, average

MySQL is still pretty new to me, so I'm having difficutly finding the answer to this particular problem.

I have roughly 60 vendor tables that I would like to join into one table. Alot of our vendors carry the same items so I would like to add all of the items to one table, and those that have the same sku, add the quantities together. I would also like to insert the greater cost and price, and round it up to .99, but if it gets too complicated or can't be sone, I will stick with just the sku's and quanitity for now. I would like to start with 2 tables until I can figure it out, then once I grasp the solution I can work on all of them. Here's an example of 2 tables:

```
Table A (SKU will be the primary key)
SKU     Vendor A SKU         Cost     Price      QTY
1000        VA100            49.99    62.99      10
1001        VA101            64.44    81.99      6
1002        VA102            37.67    47.99      24
1003        VA103            28.33    35.99      16
1004        VA104            26.33    35.99      18

Table B (SKU will be the primary key)

SKU     Vendor B SKU         Cost    Price       QTY
1000        VB100            49.99   62.95        21
1001        VB101            64.44   81.95        16
5001        VB501            32.67   40.95         4
5002        VB502            88.44   110.95      12
5003        VB503            87.21   109.95       2
```

So the End Result will look like this

```
SKU     Vendor A SKU     Vendor B SKU      Cost           Price         QTY
1000        VA100               VB100      49.99         62.99          31 <-- Sum
1001        VA101               VB101      64.44         81.99          22 <-- Sum
1002        VA102                          37.67         47.99          24
1003        VA103                          28.33         35.99          16
1004        VA104                          26.33         35.99          18
5001                            VB501      32.67         40.95           4
5002                            VB502      88.44         110.95         12
5003                            VB503      87.21         109.95          2
```

As you can see the first 2 had the quantities added together, as well as the greater of cost and price inserted. I've tried variations of:

```
Create Table MASTER
SELECT TableA.sku,TableA.VendorA_sku,TableA.cost,TableA.price,TableA.qty
UNION ALL
SELECT TableB.sku,TableB.VendorB_sku,TableB.cost,TableB.price,TableB.qty
GROUP BY sku
```

And variations of:

```
Create Table MASTER
AS SELECT TableA.sku,TableA.VendorA_sku,TableA.cost,TableA.price,SUM(TableA.qty+TableB.qty)
GROUP BY sku
```

I've tried numerous different types of Joins and unions and can't seem to get anything to look the way I need it to, nor have I played around with the adding and rounding of cost and price, as I can't get past the adding of quanitity in duplicate Primary keys. I have to do this on a daily basis with roughly 60 tables and about 600k sku's, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

(**I also Apologize in advance if I didn't type this correctly as I'm new to these types of forums**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
select sku,
  min(case when Type = 'VendorA' THEN Vendor END) VendorA_SKU,
  min(case when Type = 'VendorB' THEN Vendor END) VendorB_SKU,
  cost,  
  price, 
  sum(QTY) Total
from
(
  select sku, VendorA_SKU Vendor, cost, price, qty, 'VendorA' Type
  from tablea
  union all 
  select sku, VendorB_SKU, cost, price, qty, 'VendorB' Type
  from tableb
) x
group by sku
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a593f/11)

A few things to decide, do you want the `AVG()` or `MAX()` cost and price if the values are different or which one do you want to return?  If you do then you will use the following to return `MAX()`:

```
select sku,
  min(case when Type = 'VendorA' THEN Vendor END) VendorA_SKU,
  min(case when Type = 'VendorB' THEN Vendor END) VendorB_SKU,
  max(cost) MaxCost,
  max(price) MaxPrice,
  sum(QTY) Total
from
(
  select sku, VendorA_SKU Vendor, cost, price, qty, 'VendorA' Type
  from tablea
  union all 
  select sku, VendorB_SKU, cost, price, qty, 'VendorB' Type
  from tableb
) x
group by sku
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a593f/20)

Comment: This is what I put in to test the statement, if you can double check for me, as it looks like it worked and I want to make sure. I was a little unsure what you put in for 'VendorA'/'VendorB', as I don't have that anywhere, so I improvised

select sku,
  min(case when Type = 'eastern_sku' THEN sku END) eastern_sku,
  min(case when Type = 'western_sku' THEN sku END) western_sku,
  cost,  
  price, 
  sum(QTY) Total
from
(
  select sku, eastern_sku, cost, price, qty, 'eastern' Type
  from eastern
  union all
  select sku, oneal_sku, cost, price, qty, 'western' Type
  from western
) x
group by sku

Comment: @user1683692 happy to help, hopefully this will push you in the right direction.

Comment: One more queston. So for every additional table I need to add, I'll include another statement


  min(case when Type = 'western_sku' THEN sku END) western_sku,

  and

select sku, western_sku, cost, price, qty, 'western' Type
  from western

  for each additional tabel correct?

Comment: @user1683692 yes if you have more tables to add then you will use the `UNION ALL` to add it and then add a `CASE` to get the values in a new column.  As far as the `VendorA/VendorB` you can call it whatever you want, I just used it for my exmaple.  You need it to identify each of the records.

Comment: @user1683692 the `VendorA/VendorB` identifier is then used in the `CASE` statement.

Comment: OK, that's why it worked when I just put the vendor name in there instead. Now it's making sense. Very cool. I appreciate your help, this has given me a clear path to where I need to go to next. Now If I wanted to make one more column "Is_In_Stock", where if qty <1, then 0, if >0 then 1, (Output for this column would only be 1 or 0) I would put this in the statement as well, or would I make a separate statement all together, as this would be based off the data, but not actually included in it, so it doesn't have a table to pull the data from.

Comment: @user1683692 you can use that in the same query, just add a new column using a `CASE` something like `CASE WHEN SUM(QTY) <1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as Is_In_Stock`. You will have to test this but that should be approx correct.

Comment: BTW if you find the answer helpful, then be sure to accept it via the checkmark, it will help future visitors as well.

Comment: @user1683692 here is a sample fiddle with the `Is_In_Stock` field: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a593f/22

Comment: It works perfectly, I appreciate all your help. I should have asked this a few weeks ago, instead of trying to figure it our on my own.. Although I found out all the ways it won't work.

So, I added title to the select statement and union all statements, so each will look like this:

select sku, VendorA_SKU Vendor, title, cost, price, qty, 'VendorA' Type
  from tablea

  My only concern with the title is, since each has a title, will they conflict with each other, or will each union all thereafter only add a title if the record is null?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean by title, I do not see why it would cause any conflicts.  But if it does, then post a new question and someone will most likely be able to help you.  I am glad you got it working. :)